# Using the contents fo an array in Spring EL

Tags: java, spring, spring-el, spring-cache

I am using Spring's caching facility. When I call the following method, I want to evict the cache for all the values in the array `receiptObject.resolverIds`:

```
@Override
@Caching(evict = {
        @CacheEvict(value = "assignedFeedbacks", key = "#receiptObject.resolverIds[0]"),
        @CacheEvict(value = "newFeedbacks", key = "#receiptObject.feedbackObject.serviceId") })
public void addReceipt(ReceiptObject receiptObject) throws Exception {
    feedbackDao.insertReceipt(receiptObject);
}
```

Here I have only used the first element but I want to generalize this for all the elements in the array. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you have somewhere a `@Cacheable` method like this:

```
@Cacheable(value = "assignedFeedbacks")
public void getReceipt(Object receiptId) throws Exception {
```

Since `@Caching` annotations can get deal only with single cache entry at once, there is no reason to take a look how SpEL can can work with arrays, because the `key` should be a single object.

The only way I see is based on the direct Cache Abstraction usage:

```
@Autowired
private CacheManager cacheManager;

public void addReceipt(ReceiptObject receiptObject) throws Exception {
    feedbackDao.insertReceipt(receiptObject);
    Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache("assignedFeedbacks");
    for (Object receiptId: receiptObject.getResolverIds()) {
        cache.evict(receiptId);
    }
}
```